# Triggering a click event from within an angularjs function causes an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm getting the error

> [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

whenever I trigger a click event on a hidden file upload input.

HTML:

```
<!-- button that calls function in controller -->
<button type="button" ng-click="uploadClicked()">Upload</button>
<!-- Upload input I'm triggering the click event on -->
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="profile-photo" name="profile-photo" ng-hide="true"/>
```

AngularJS function in controller:

```
$scope.uploadClicked = function () {
    //Causes Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress and opens file dialog
    document.getElementById('profile-photo').click();

    //Causes Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress and does not open file dialog
    $('#profile-photo').trigger('click');
};
```

I'm not calling `$apply` or `$digest` anywhere in my controller. Why would this error be occurring?

Comment: Because angularjs does some actions in the background and  your tiggered `click` conflicts at that place.

Comment: That's rather unfortunate. Any advice on how to circumvent this?

Comment: Try wrapping it in a $timeout

Comment: @justine have you had any luck with this ?I am facing the same issue.I am manually clicking on a hidden link for downloading and this error is thrown then.Please update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got a similar issue and i was able to fix that by wrapping the place where we click with a

```
 setTimeout(function(){uploadClicked();},0);
```

the angular version would be

```
$timeout(function(){uploadClicked();},0);
```

By using angular version, Angular  will be aware and will not initialize another digest cycle on finding a click event.

Comment: It should be setTimeout, not setTimeOut (no capital O).

Comment: Actually, it would be $timeout(function() { uploadClicked(); }) these days